# DATA_ID always send the first row id to JQUERY

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, thymeleaf

I'm actually trying to create a modal(confirm box) for delete list and when I'm trying to delete it by using (commented code below)the "confirm box" it works very well, but when I pass it through the onclick to my jquery it will always delete the first row. Please someone help me.

```html
  < td >
      < a th: data - id = "${users.id}"  id = "elem" class = "open-button" >
      < i class = "btn-icon-only icon-remove" > < /i>                                        < /a > < /td >
      <!--   <td><a class="btn btn-small" onclick="if (confirm('Adakah anda pasti untuk memadamkan item yang dipilih?')){return true;}else{event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();};" 
  th: href = "@{/deleteUser/{id}(id=${users.id})}" >
      < i class = "btn-icon-only icon-remove" > < /i>                                        < /a > < /td > -->

  < td >
      < div id = "confirm" >
      < div class = "message" > Adakah anda pasti untuk memadamkan item yang dipilih ? < /div> < a class = "btn btn-small"
  onclick = "if (confirm('Item akan dipadam')){return true;}else{event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();};"
  th: href = "@{/deleteUser/{id}(id=${users.id})}" >
      PADAM < /a> < button class = "no" > KEMBALI < /button > < /div>

  < /td>
```

adminlist.js

```
  function functionAlert(element, msg, myYes) {

      var confirmBox = $("#confirm");

      var dataId = $("#elem").data("id");

      console.log(dataId);

      confirmBox.find(".message").text(msg);
      confirmBox.find(".no").unbind().click(function() {
          confirmBox.hide();

      });
      confirmBox.find(".no").click(myYes);
      confirmBox.show();
  }
```

I knew that it always carry the first row id, because whenever I console it, it will alwys show the first row id, can some help me to get the id by row based on the selected item

Comment: why does your HTML have so many spaces! Does your HTML have more than one element with `id="confirm"` or `id="elem"` - if so, how should jQuery know which one your code refers to? This is why id's must be unique in HTML

Comment: Please format your html properly.